# How to get the OPTION's TEXT value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In this case, only primary dropdown will change, other dropdowns' values will change automatically according to it (so users wont be changing them) I'm trying to get the **Option's TEXT value** using PHP with $_POST. But i can only get it when i **manually** changed the other dropdown .
I have tried to use the trigger() method, but it fails to get the option text value. Any idea why the code fails to work. Thank you.

```js
function setDropDown() {
  var index_name =
    document.getElementsByName('ForceSelection')[0].selectedIndex;
  var others = document.querySelectorAll('.secondary');
  for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i++) {
    others[i].selectedIndex = index_name;
  }
}
<!-- try to get the option text value and pass it to input field-->
<!-- Then in the php code use $_POST[] to retrieve the input value-->
function setTextField(ddl) {
  document.getElementById('make_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
}

$("select").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<div><b>Primary dropdown:</b>
  <select name="ForceSelection" id="ForceSelection" onChange="javascript:return setDropDown();">
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
<option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <b>Other dropdown 1</b>:
  <select class='secondary' id="Qualifications" name="Qualifications" onChange="setTextField(this)">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
    </select></div>
<input id="make_text" type="hidden" name="make_text" value="" />


<div> <b>Other dropdown 2</b>:
  <select class='secondary' id="Qualifications2" name="Qualifications2">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
   $value =$_POST['make_text'];
```

Comment: Why this is `<input id="make_text" type = "hidden" name = "make_text" value = "" />` inside select dropdown?

Comment: I cant see a `<form>` or an ajax call that suggest you are POSTING values on the server. Can add it to example please

Comment: @Stamos Updated, plz have a look,thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Html element `<select>` onchange doesn't fire for programmatic changes, you need to fire it yourself with

`$(".secondary").trigger("change");`

or by Id

`$("#Qualifications").trigger("change");`

The problem is that your hidden `<input>` never had the value. if you remove the hidden it on your code you can check it.

So when you POSTED the values the value on `make_text` was empty string. So if you fire the trigger after the `for` loop then it will work.

```js
function setDropDown() {

var index_name = document.getElementsByName('ForceSelection')[0].selectedIndex;

var others = document.querySelectorAll('.secondary');

for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i++) {

 others[i].selectedIndex = index_name;

}

$("#Qualifications").trigger("change");

}

function setTextField(ddl) {

document.getElementById('make_text').value = ddl.value;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<div><b>Primary dropdown:</b>
  <select name="ForceSelection" id="ForceSelection" onChange="javascript:return setDropDown();">
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
<option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <b>Other dropdown 1</b>:
  <select class='secondary' id="Qualifications" name="Qualifications" onChange="setTextField(this)">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
    </select></div>
<input id="make_text"  name="make_text" value="" />


<div> <b>Other dropdown 2</b>:
  <select class='secondary' id="Qualifications2" name="Qualifications2">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="treatmentid1">treatmentname1</option>
    <option value="treatmentid2">treatmentname2</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: What if instead of showing the option value in the input field, can it be the option text? Thank you

Comment: There is no need for hidden input in order to take the values on post. If you do `$value =$_POST['Qualifications'];` it should have the selected value of select element. Also even if the input is hidden you will get the value.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am wondering can I  get the **option TEXT value (i.e treatmentname1) **instead of the option value (i.e treatmentid1).Many Thanks!!

Comment: you can do your own POST with `$.ajax` on form submit. carefull you will have to `return false;` onsubmit so you wont POST twice

Comment: I'm sorry, still very new to javascript stuff, is there a more simple way in doing this instead of using ajax

Comment: Is it possible if u could provide any code snippet as a reference, thankyou

Comment: So I figure out another way to attain what I need. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I don't see any need to use a hidden input text to POST data to PHP because you can just post the value of the `<select>` and retrieve it in **PHP** like this `$force = $_POST["ForceSelection"];`.

**Otherwise**, if you want to continue what you started, you can change your `setDropDown()` function to this :

```
function setDropDown() {
  #Get the selected value of the ForceSelection select : 
  var index_name = $('#ForceSelection').val();
  #Change the value of the other secondary select : 
  $(".secondary").each(function( index ) {
      $(this).val(index_name).change();//This will change the value and trigger the change event.
  });

}
```